# Calculating flux over an area of a triangle?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $T$ be the triangle with the vertices $\{(-1,0) , (1,1), (0,2)\}$ traversed in the anticlockwise direction. let $\hat{a}$ be the outward normal to $T$ in the $xy$ plane

Evaluate 
$$ \oint_{\partial T} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{a} \, ds $$

where

$$\vec{F}(x,y) = (2x^2 + 3x -2 \cos^4(y) \sin^3(y) , 4 e^{2x} \sinh(x) - 3y)$$

Comment: Have you made any attempt at the problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Using divergence theorem, the divergence of F(x,y) = dFx/dx + dFy/dy and integrate that over the the triangular area.

dFx/dx + dFy/dy = 4x + 3 - 3 = 4x

So by the divergence theorem, the integral is the double integral of (4 x) dA over the triangular area, which is four times the x-coordiante of the triangle centroid, given by (-1 + 1 + 0)/3 = 0, so the integral is 4 (0) = 0.

But I think I am completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Best here to use Stoke's theorem.  This may be done by recognizing that $\hat{a}=\hat{z}$, and rewriting $\vec{F}(x,y) = (2x^2 + 3x -2 \cos^4(y) \sin^3(y) , 4 e^{2x} \sinh(x) - 3y,0)$.  Then

$$\nabla \times \vec{F} \cdot \hat{z} = \left (\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} \right )\cdot \hat{z}$$

The line integral above may be expressed as a double integral over $T$:

$$\iint_T dx dy \, \left (\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} \right ) $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\Large\tt Hint:$
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec{F}
=
\pars{4x + 3} + \pars{-3} = \nabla\cdot\pars{2x^{2}\hat{x}}
\quad\imp\quad
\nabla\cdot\pars{\vec{F} - 2x^{2}\hat{x}} = 0
$$
Then, $\vec{F} - 2x^{2}\hat{x} = \nabla\times\vec{A}$
and
$$
\int_{S}\vec{F}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
=
2\quad\overbrace{\quad\int_{S}x^{2}\hat{x}\cdot\dd\vec{S}\quad}
^{=\ 0\,\quad\mbox{Why ?}}
+
\int\vec{A}\cdot\dd\vec{r}
$$
It's easier to integrate over three line segments. You have to determine $\vec{A}$:

$$
\partiald{A_{z}}{y} - \partiald{A_{y}}{z} = F_{x} - 2x^{2}\,,
\quad
\partiald{A_{x}}{z} - \partiald{A_{z}}{x} = F_{y}\,, 
\quad
\partiald{A_{y}}{x} - \partiald{A_{x}}{y} = 0 
$$